# How to convert dictionary keys to array of strings (insert at array index as specified in dictionary.value)

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

```
Dictionary<String, UInt32> dict = new Dictionary<String, UInt32>();
dict.Add("1", 1);
dict.Add("4", 4);
dict.Add("5", 5);
```

Quick way to convert all keys to array is

```
string[] keys = dict.Keys.ToArray();
```

This is how memory representation of array would look

`keys[0] = "1" keys[1] = "4" keys[2] = "5"`

What I want is, key string value should be in array at the index specified by value.

```
keys[1] = "1" keys[4] = "4" keys[5] = "5"
```

This is what I tried, it works..

```
Int32 count = -1;
foreach (KeyValuePair<String, UInt32> kvp in dict)
{
    if (kvp.Value > count)
    {
        count = (Int32)kvp.Value;
    }
}

String[] labelarray = new String[count + 1];
foreach (KeyValuePair<String, UInt32> kvp in dict)
{
    labelarray[kvp.Value] = kvp.Key;
}
```

But Is there any better, cleaner way to do above?

Comment: Well, you could use `int count = list.Values.Max();` instead of the first part of your code. I'd also strongly urge you not to use the name `list` for a dictionary...

Comment: And what should be in the other indexes, for example 0, 2, 3, 6?

Comment: What do you want to have in the in between? keys[0], keys[2], keys[3]?

Comment: Could you describe what are you trying to achieve? For now you are creating unnecessary array elements for an unknown purpose.

Comment: I want to utilize String[] somewhere, I think I have given all details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657(v=vs.110).aspx) to revert keys and values.

```
var revertedDictionary = list.ToDictionary(x => x.Value, x => x.Key);
```

Another way with `List<T>` or `Array` has 2 parts: searching max index and filling collection:

```
if(!list.Any())
{
    // use different behavior if you need
    return new string[0];
}
var maxValue = list.Values.Max();
var newList = new string[maxValue];
Enumerable
      .Range(0, (int)maxValue)
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(x => newList[x] = list.ContainsValue((uint)x) ? x.ToString() : string.Empty);

// improve memory usage by preventing to create new List in ToList() method
foreach(var index in Enumerable.Range(0, (int)maxValue))
{
    newList[index] = list.ContainsValue((uint)index) ? index.ToString() : string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work with Empty dictionary. Max() throws exception for obvious reasons

Comment: @VadimMartynov, why do you need to use Enumerable.Range? Can you just go through the orignal dictionary and fill in the new array?

Comment: One more thing, I want String[] output not revertedDictionary

Comment: @Helic yes, @user1 can enumerate to the original dictionary but then you need to initialize target collection with empty strings first. It can depend on expected behavior but string values initialize with `null` values by default.

Comment: @user1 TY for additional comment, I add extra checking to my second solution. The second part will return `String[]`. I just added alternative code for example.